# Can I use Op-Amps to drive a ultrasonic piezo transducer at 200kHz

Tags: operational-amplifier, ultrasound, piezo, transducer

I’ll admit I’m not the most knowledgeable guy when it comes to electronic circuits, so I thought I’d ask before breaking anything.

I’m looking to drive a piezo transducer using a 200kHz sine wave. The transducers should have a relatively low impedance of around 150Ohms. While searching on the web I only found complicated amplifier circuits or expensive piezo amplifiers. I’m wondering if it’s possible to do this using simple op-amps.

My first question is if I could just hook up a function generator and an oscilloscope to find/check the resonance frequency. (Look for the maximum voltage on the oscilloscope and a 90° phase to the current). I know that piezo transducer can have high voltage spikes, that might damage the function generator?

Next, I’d like to amplify the sine signal to about 60Vpp. The simplest way I could think of, was to use two parallel 30V op-amps, one having an inverted sine signal. Thus, the transducer would have 60Vpp. The current needed would be around 400mA, so taking two cheap op-amps with a 250mA output should do the job? I calculated slew rate of 38V/us and a bandwidth of 6MHz, which shouldn’t be a problem when looking for op-amps. Is this setup possible, or am I missing something important about piezo transducers?

Comment: You’re forgetting the 24W peak power load use a small CMOS full bridge with a 30V supply and resonant choke with current sense and limiter

Comment: Or without choke if you want wide BW but each driver must be rated >400 mA

Comment: If you're using a 'bridge' configuration with 2 amps to 'double' the Vpp output voltage then each amp sees the full current, not half.